# How to make particles in SCNParticleSystem opaque?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, particles

I created a SceneKit Scene File > Particle System and I can't figure out how to make all the particles opaque. The default particles alpha setting seems random. I change the image and a few other properties, and took a screen shot:

[image]

I've tried:

```
particle.particleColorVariation = SCNVector4(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Which only makes the particles around 80%-90% transparent, but I cannot get it 100% opaque.

Answer (score 2):

To make a particle system be fully opaque you need to set a [blendMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticleblendmode) instance property to `.alpha` (default value is `.additive`) and [sortingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesortingmode) instance property set to `.distance` (default value is `.none`)

```
var blendMode: SCNParticleBlendMode { get set }
var sortingMode: SCNParticleSortingMode { get set }
```

According to Apple documentation:

> `.blendMode` is the blending mode for compositing particle images into the rendered scene.

There are six compositing **blend modes** for particles in SceneKit:

- `.additive`
- `.alpha`
- `.multiply`
- `.replace`
- `.screen`
- `.subtract`

Here's how it looks in real code:

```
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
scnView.scene = scene
scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
particleSystem.birthRate = 5

particleSystem.blendMode = .alpha         // 100% opaque if alpha = 1.0
particleSystem.sortingMode = .distance
particleSystem.particleSize = 1.0
particleSystem.emitterShape = SCNSphere(radius: 5)
particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 100
particleSystem.particleColor = .red

// No Alpha variation
particleSystem.particleColorVariation = SCNVector4(1, 1, 1, 0)

let particlesNode = SCNNode()
particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick: particleSystem.alpha = 1.0; particleSystem.particleAlphaRange = 0.0. I set it in the particle file.